# What could be our Honbu name?

Tags: comparative-linguistics

In Japan and in Japanese the Honbu of Judo is called Kodakan [講道館] or a place for the study of the way...  I would like to know, if in appropriate Japanese language it would be possible to discover a word that could be a "place for the study of" an art named "geido kenpo ninpo ryu'?  We use a shortened translation for geido kenpo ninpo ryu - in English such as "Artistic Combative Enlightenment".